# How do I test for HTTP method in a GraphEngine server endpoint?

Tags: c#, rest, graphengine

The [GraphEngine docs](http://www.graphengine.io/docs/manual/TSL/MPProtocol.html#http-protocols) say that HTTP protocols are RESTful. I am trying to implement such, but I can't find any information about testing for the HTTP method that is being used to call the endpoint.

To my understanding, that is essential for something to be RESTful, right? The methods GET, POST, PUT and DELETE map to CRUD-like SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE operations.

I have looked at the sample applications, and they all have non-RESTful-sounding names, like PostTweet or SearchTweet. It leads me to wonder, have the authors of GraphEngine just missed the heart of REST and simplified it to mean RPC via HTTP? Or, is there actually a way to handle the different HTTP methods in a Handler?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this question answered by sending it to the GraphEngine support email address. Their response:

> You are right, TSL HTTP protocols are 'RPC over HTTP'.  It is ok to
>   call these protocols via HTTP GET/POST. However, other HTTP verbs
>   (e.g. DELETE) are currently not supported.